# @pnp/sp seems to be missing the .get() method

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-2016

I am running into a strange (and hopefully very simple) issue where the .get() method does not seem to be defined in my spfx project.
This is a typescript 2.4.2 project for creating an spfx webpart for SharePoint 2016 on prem.

- The project was started using yo @microsoft/sharepoint
- There was a fix applied to update some typescript 2.2.2 references as per instructions [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/SPFx-On-Premesis-2016/)
- The dependencies for PnP were loaded:

  npm install @pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/sp --save
- Imports included

  import { sp, Web } from '@pnp/sp';

Within a function of my render() method I am trying to make a very simple call as follows

```
let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl);

return web.lists.getByTitle(this.properties.listName).fields.filter("Title eq 'Decision Status'").get();
```

I am getting an error that says Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Fields'. To try and make it even simpler I tried running

```
let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl);
web.get();
```

And I get a similar error saying 'get' does not exist on type 'Web'. The examples they show in the documentation show very similar code, but I can't determine what about my code is incorrect here.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is still relevant,check the version of the `@pnp/sp` installed. The latest one as of today is `1.2.9` and should support `get`

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this issue, my solution was install this others dependencies with the same version.

```
@pnp/common
@pnp/logging
@pnp/odata
@pnp/sp
```

hope that helps for anyone with this problem!